# Como obtener lista de objetos de un json (C#, Api Rest, Firebase)

Tags: c#, json, firebase, rest, realtime-database

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con C#, Unity y Firebase (Realtime Database) y accedo a los datos con una api rest. La base de datos solo guarda a los usuarios con sus datos, como se ve en la imagen.

En C# tengo un objeto Usuario con los atributos (nombre, email, contraseña y puntuacion), y he conseguido acceder a los datos de cada usuario por separado con este codigo:

```
 RestClient.Get<Usuario>("https://proyectojuego-b75ec-default- 
 rtdb.firebaseio.com/pepe.json").Then(response => {
                Usuario usuario = response; 
                Debug.Log(usuario.nombre);
                Debug.Log(usuario.email);       
        });
```

Esto me permite almacenar los datos de un usuario de la base de datos en un objeto Usuario. Poniendo al final de la URL el nombre del usuario al que quiero acceder.
https://proyectojuego-b75ec-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/pepe.json

Pero ahora necesito almacenar todos los usuarios de la base de datos en una lista de usuarios, he intentado guardar todos los datos en una lista usando la URL donde aparecen todos los datos. https://proyectojuego-b75ec-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json
Pero no funciona..

```
RestClient.Get<List<Usuario>>("https://proyectojuego-b75ec-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json").Then(response => {
                
            List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = new List<Usuario>(); 
            listaUsuarios = response;
    
            Debug.Log(listaUsuarios[0].nombre); 
            Debug.Log(listaUsuarios[1].email); 
    });
```

No funciona porque el response no devuelve una lista y tiene una estructura clave-valor, pero realmente no tengo ni idea como hacerlo. Alguien conoce alguna forma sencilla de poder hacer lo que quiero y guardar todos los Objetos Usuario en una lista de Objetos Usuarios??

No entiendo mucho del funcionamiento de los json ni las Api Rest, pero espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, gracias^^

Comment: La estructura del Json parece ser como un diccionario, porque tiene "nombre": {DatosDelUsuario}. Intenta castearlo a un `Dictionary<string, Usuario>` en vez de un `List<Usuario>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instala la librería Newtonsoft.Json con el administrador de de paquetes NuGet

[image: Administrador de paquetes NuGet]

Después solo tienes que deserializar el Json que te retorna el endpoint del api al listado de objetos que ya tienes:

```
RestClient.Get<List<Usuario>>("https://proyectojuego-b75ec-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json").Then(response => {
            // JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> deserializa un json string en un objeto de tipo T
            Dictionary<string, Usuario> respuesta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Usuario>>(response);
            List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = respuesta.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();        

            Debug.Log(listaUsuarios[0].nombre); 
            Debug.Log(listaUsuarios[1].email); 
    });
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, he intentado lo que dices, pero en la parte de JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Usuario>>(response), me marca un error en rojo en response, el error es: Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Usuario>' a 'string', al parecer entre los parentesis solo acepta que meta un string, ¿Sabes como puedo solucionarlo? @Hansel Ch

Comment: Que tipo de dato es la variable response? si ya es Dictionary<string, Usuario>, no tienes que deserializar, simplemente convierte el diccionario en List usando response.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

Comment: ¿Que que tipo de dato? ni idea, supongo que lo que yo le quiera poner.. he probado con RestClient.Get<List<Usuario>> y con RestClient.Get<Dictionary<string, Usuario>>, tampoco entiendo mucho de eso, y los datos que hay en el response son los de la url. y he probado a usar directamente List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = response.Select(x => x.Value).ToList(); y nada, la lista esta vacia.

Comment: Desconozco  que librería estas usando para esta función `RestClient.Get<T>(url)` pero supondría que la T es el tipo de dato en que serializa el response, por lo que debería ir `RestClient.Get<Dictionary<string, Usuario>>`, igual para estar seguro por favor añade esto antes de listaUsuarios y di que te sale `Console.WriteLine(response.GetType());`

Comment: Con Console.WriteLine no me ha devuelto nada, con Debug.Log me da devuelto: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Usuario], y para esa funcion lo que estoy usando es https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient

Answer (score 0):

Para unity yo uso proyecto26

https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient

Estas usando RestClient.Get<List>("uri");

Pero proyecto26 tiene **RestClient.GetArray< Usuario >("uri");**

```
RestClient.GetArray<Usuario>("uri").Then(response => {
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog ("Success", JsonHelper.ArrayToJson<Usuario>(response, true), "Ok");});
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta, para unity yo tambien estoy usando proyecto26. He intentado usar el codigo que pasaste, pero ArrayToJson me lo marca en rojo, "'JsonHelper' no contiene una definición para 'ArrayToJson'", sabes que puedo hacer? he seguido intentando pero no consigo acceder a los datos.

Comment: He probado con ArrayToJsonString, pero no me devuelte nada. En la ventana solo me sale "Items": []